# In Inversion of Control, what is the difference between a callback and dependency injection?

Tags: dependency-injection, callback, inversion-of-control

I understand what's going on enough to know I'm missing something.  I get how in DI I'm using and Interface or Abstract Class to define what my function/method can receive.  As long as my object implements or extends the given type, I can pass it to, good decoupling.

In a callback, I'm passing a function to a method that calls my other function.  LIke in C, I can use function pointers.  OOP language same thing but with Interfaces/Abstract Classes.

I see the decoupling, why that's good, the software can be extended, and so on, but not the difference between the two.

What am I missing?

EDIT: Is DI the pattern and a Callback the implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Dependency injection is a software design pattern which as you say lets you decouple your code. Making for example the ability to swap your SQL backend with an Oracle backend or swapping email hosts in dev environment or live.

This naturally descourages adding say database code to your front end project which is obviously not a great idea.

A callback or delegate is where you pass in some code as a parameter to a method. You see this a lot in things like collections where you may want to use different sort functionality in different consumer code.

So if you where to write your own DI container, you would be binding a reference to an interface, say IRepository to a concrete implemention, say SQLRepository or WebRepository. Your DI code what allow consumers to define which concrete implementation to use at compile time either using a configuration file (e.g. unity) or in code (Ninject).

Comment: Thanks.  In your last paragraph, how is that different from using a callback?  Are you saying DI is the pattern and Callbacks are the implementation?

Comment: See this example of IOC with code: http://joelabrahamsson.com/inversion-of-control-an-introduction-with-examples-in-net/ and this explanation of callbacks from wikipedia In computer programming, a callback is a reference to executable code, or a piece of executable code, that is passed as an argument to other code. This allows a lower-level software layer to call a subroutine (or function) defined in a higher-level layer.

Comment: I did not see anything about callbacks in the article.

Comment: No. IOC/ DI is not the pattern and callbacks are the implementation. They have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: That is the reason for my question.  What's the difference?

Comment: I'm not sure how to put this succinctly, but DI is where you bind code together in a config file or in code. Callbacks are where you pass code in as a parameter.

Comment: @johnny Think of the callback function as a dependency of the object that it is being passed into. DI is the process of providing the callback (the dependency) to the object. (For example: by giving it to the object via its constructor, a method call, a setter, etc.).

Comment: I downvoted the answer because it is plain wrong. Dependency Injection is a pattern in which the instantiation and implementation details are controlled by the caller.  And yes callbacks are one way that dependency injection can be achieved. Other ways are through constructor parameters or property assignments.  More sophisticated tools will do do it through the use of reflection.

Comment: What you have said here doesn't disagree with my answer. I never said that callbacks are the only way to achieve DI